# Cannot add migration in RubyMine 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine, rails-migrations

I'm trying to add a new column to a model in RubyMine 6/ Ruby 2.0/ Rails 4.
I run a generator with parameter migration and the following options:
add_mbti_test_to_profile mbti_test:string
and nothing happens. It says the command executed successfully:

> /home/eiskarlsson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -e
> $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)
> /home/eiskarlsson/RubymineProjects/MyLexikon.com/bin/rails generate
> migration add_mbti_test_to_profile mbti_test:string
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Can someone help me figure this out?!

I changed the Ruby and Rails versions, but still no migration in the db/migrate folder:

/home/eiskarlsson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;
load($0=ARGV.shift) /home/eiskarlsson/RubymineProjects/MyLexikon.com/bin/rails generate
migration AddMbtiTestToProfiles mbti_test:string -t -f

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: have you checked your 'db/migrate' directory for any new files?

Comment: There should be a button with two arrows in circle - it resynchronises IDE with the files. Try clicking it.

Comment: yes, I checked db/migrate directory and there are no new files. Resynchronizing doesn't help either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can anyone come up with something else? I am not sure where to look for information on what has changed after running the above command.